# Web Installer XML referring files from TFS

Tags: properties, tfs, wix, location

```
<Component Id="ProductComponent1">
  <File Id="Default.aspxName="Default.aspx"Source="..\WebApplication2\Default.aspx"  />
</Component>
```

What modification would help include the same file from TFS rather than my local system.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any mechanism by which a WIX build can pull files directly from Team Foundation Server (TFS).  If this is your intention, you could use a `tf get` command to pull the latest version prior to the WIX build. For more information on `tf get` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf(v=vs.100).aspx.

If the WIX project is part of a Team Build, the answer to this question may be relevant: [Set location of binaries in wixproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30252746/set-location-of-binaries-in-wixproj-file/).